# Why is R automatically using Yates' correction?

Tags: r, yates-correction

I wanted to understand why R is always running Yates' correction for a 2$\times$2 contingency table. My strategy is to create some random 2$\times$2 contingency tables (let's say a thousand) and do X² test with or without Yates' correction and maybe a Fisher test to see which test is closer to the theoretical number of p.value < 0.05 which should be if I'm not wrong 5%.

Here are the results:

- Without Yates' correction : 52 pvalues < 0.05 /1000 runs
- X² with Yates's correction: 33 pvalues < 0.05
- Fisher : 40 pvalues < 0.05

So sadly  I can not conclude since it is not helping me to understand why Yates' correction is automatically used by R since my results show that this correction seems to be over conservative (by the way, I am surprised that the X² seems more accurate than Fisher.test)

Being a novice in both statistics and programming, I ignore if my strategy is relevant.

Here is the script :

```
# Value choice
nb.Runs = 1000    # number of try
effectif = 100    

Yateslist <- 0
Chilist <- 0
Fisherlist <- 0

for (i in 1:nb.Runs){
sujets = matrix((rnorm(effectif*2, mean=0, sd=1)<0), effectif, ncol=2)
conting = table(as.data.frame(sujets))

Yates.pval=chisq.test(conting)$p.value
Chi.pval=chisq.test(conting, correct=FALSE)$p.value
Fisher.pval=fisher.test(conting)$p.value

if(Yates.pval <= 0.05){Yateslist = Yateslist + 1}
if(Chi.pval <= 0.05){Chilist = Chilist + 1}
if(Fisher.pval <= 0.05){Fisherlist = Fisherlist + 1}
}

# Results
cat("Nombre de significatifs :", "\n")
cat("Yates", Yateslist, "\n")
cat("Sans corr", Chilist, "\n")
cat("Fisher", Fisherlist, "\n")
cat("sur", nb.Runs, "essais", "\n")
```

Comment: The $2\times 2$ $\chi^{2}$ contingency table test is inappropriate when the *expected* number of counts in any cell is < 4. I do not see code sanitizing these tests, so your simulation is probably not representative of practice.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this question will have an answer for "why" since that would be speculating about the R programmer's intentions. Therefore, I don't think it's a relevant question to ask. The source code for the `chisq.test` function does not reveal code comments, and the function [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.4.3/topics/chisq.test) also doesn't give an indication. The only relevant reference is to Alan Agresti's book, which may have suggested the use of a Yates' correction in place of no continuity correction.